# How to call a contract's method via web3 1.x without a node (sign with a privateKey and send)?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

There's a number of questions and answers about calling contract methods via web3, but they are either outdated (i.e. for web3 0.x while 1.x has many breaking changes) and/or don't include signing ([1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/8736/40080), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48184969/3995261), [3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/21402/40080)). The first steps, as far as I understand, should be these:

```
import Web3 from "web3"
import { AbiItem } from "web3-utils"

;(async() => {
    const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(...)
    const web3 = new Web3(provider)

    // see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/98149/40080 and https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/3310#issuecomment-997396686
    const abi = ... as AbiItem[] // imported from a file
    const methodName = ...
    const callParameters = [
        ...
    ]
    const contractAddress = ...
    const universeContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress)

    const call = universeContract.methods[methodName](callParameters)
})()
```

but then I also have to sign this with private key and send, and this is what I haven't achieved yet. According to [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/25610/40080), I should be using [`eth.accounts.sign(data, privateKey)`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#sign) (since I have to do this without a node), but I have no idea what `data` I should extract from `call` and how (and how to further send it). Can somebody show how to do this or at least give some pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a proper Web3 instance setup, the below is how I generally make contract calls from the server using a class (or where you have a fixed key that requires no user input). I use an instance of the Hyperledger Besu version of Ethereum, so if you use a different provider it might vary slightly. Also, if you are asking the user to sign the transaction, it's a different process, but from your question it sounded like you are using a fixed key without input.

```
this.contract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

let tx = {
   from: fromAddress,
   to: this.contract.options.address,
   gasPrice: gasPrice,
   gas: gasAmount,
   data: await this.contract.methods.methodName(param1, param2, ...).encodeABI()
};

let signedTx = await this.web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey);
let result = await this.web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
```